# XMLHTTP and "Access denied" error

Tags: delphi, xmlhttprequest, msxml

I'm trying to retrieve a content of HTTP document with MS XMLHTTP COM. I did copied the following sample code but even this does not work and fails with *EOLEException error 'Access is denied' at send method call*.

```
uses
  MSXML, ComObj, ActiveX;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  httpDoc: XMLHTTP;  // IXMLHTTPRequest
begin
    httpDoc := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP') as XMLHTTP;
  try
    httpDoc.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com/index.html', False, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
    httpDoc.send('');  // <-- EOLEException 'Access is denied'
    if (httpDoc.readyState = 4) and (httpDoc.status = 200) then
      ShowMessage(httpDoc.responseText);
  finally
    httpDoc := nil;
  end;
end;
```

I really don't know what am I doing wrong :(

Comment: Also check if `send` is really allow empty string parameter instead of canonical `null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google does location-based redirections, and sometimes that involves redirecting to another domain.  `XMLHTTP` does not like that.  Also, it seems `XMLHTTP` does not allow access to remote servers when running from a local script (such as from VB, Delphi, etc) outside of a browser. See [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxjscript/thread/876d8f68-9051-4c50-997b-e018eb1cd6d1), [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/xmlandnetfx/thread/1abda1ce-e23c-4d0e-bccd-a323aa7f2ea5), and [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505.aspx).

Comment: Marked as an answer. Although I have to blame devs of MSXML as they do not offer handling of x-domain redirects cases so programmer is forced to invent some workarounds. Not to mention obscure/non-descriptive error messages.

Comment: If you read the articles I linked to, they say you can use the `ServerXMLHTTP` object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762278.aspx) to accomplish what you are attempting. Also have a look at the `XDomainRequest` object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303.aspx).